# Enabling a single button from an array of data enclosing in .map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, setstate

Need your help with regards to enabling button when click INSIDE .map

Here's the data from backend:

file :[
{
id: 1
color: orange,
shape: triangle
}
{
id: 2
color: blue,
shape: circle
}
{
id: 3
color: red,
shape: rectangle
}
]

And this is the file rendered in .map way:

{file.map(file => (

```
  `<div>
      <a
        onClick={() => this.downloadFile(file)}
        href="javascript:void(0);"
      >
        {file.fileName}
      </a>
```

`</div>`

```
        <Button
          onClick={() => this.submit()}
          disabled={should be enabled when click}
        >
          submit
      </Button>
```

))}

In UI, it looks like this:

LINK--------------Button (this is disabled)
LINK--------------Button (this is disabled)
LINK--------------Button (this is disabled)

What i need is a function that when i click the first LINK, it only enable the first button beside it, what i have now is when i click the first LINK, it enables all the button

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an active button index to your state

```
this.state = {
  // ... any other state
  activeButtonIndex: null,
};
```

When a button is clicked set the `activeButtonIndex` to the mapped index of the button. Also use the `activeButtonIndex` to compare against the current mapping index and disable the button when they match.

```
{file.map((file, index) => (
  <div>
    <a
      onClick={() => this.downloadFile(file)}
      href="javascript:void(0);"
    >
      {file.fileName}
    </a>
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        this.submit();
        this.setState({ activeButtonIndex: index }); // <-- set active index
      }}
      disabled={index === this.state.activeButtonIndex} // <-- check active index
    >
      submit
    </Button>
  </div> 
))}
```

## Edit to allow multiple active

Add an active button index *object* to your state

```
this.state = {
  // ... any other state
  activeButtonIndex: {},
};
```

When a button is clicked add the mapped index to the `activeButtonIndex` object. Also use the `activeButtonIndex` object to compare against the current mapping index and disable the button when that index is in the `activeButtonIndex` object.

```
{file.map((file, index) => (
  <div>
    <a
      onClick={() => this.downloadFile(file)}
      href="javascript:void(0);"
    >
      {file.fileName}
    </a>
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        this.submit();
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          activeButtonIndex: {
            ...prevState.activeButtonIndex, // <-- copy existing state
            [index]: true, // <-- set active index
          },
        }));
      }}
      disabled={this.state.activeButtonIndex[index]} // <-- check active index
    >
      submit
    </Button>
  </div> 
))}
```

Comment: Close! it enables the first LINK. but when you click the seconde LINK, the first LINK is disabled again.

Comment: @ZachDLR So you want these buttons to essentially be toggles? or just allow more than 1 active at a time?

Comment: yes, when i click the first LINK, it only enables the first, and for the second LINK, the second button, but the first button should be enabled as well since we already click the first one. thanks

Comment: @ZachDLR Use a map/object to store active indices. I updated my answer with changes.

Comment: thanks Drew, working now, just that, i put the "this.setState(prevState => ({" from Button to <a> tag, that's what i needed. thanks

Comment: @ZachDLR Great, I was a bit thrown off by your last comment and the fact you accepted my answer. I assumed you were able to resolve it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the state when the first link is clicked. It can be stored in localStorage or cookie. Then you'll have to retrieve it in your component.

Or, if your link is not redirecting users to another page, then you can simply store the state in your component. For example,

```
this.state = {
  isClicked = true
}
```

Comment: Already used that, the problem is all of the three buttons go enable,

Comment: Tried ```disabled={this.state.isClicked}```?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you are storing your loaded data in state. You should need an individual toggle for each button

```
state = {
    data : []
}
this.apiCallToGetData().then(res => {
    //set all buttons to disabled by default
   res.map(r => {r.disabled = true;})
  this.setState({data: res})
});
```

In your HTML, make the disabled property dynamic and pass the index to the downloadFile function:

```
{file.map((file, index) => (
  <div>
    <a
      onClick={() => this.downloadFile(file, index)}
      href="javascript:void(0);"
    >
      {file.fileName}
    </a>
    <Button
        onClick={() => this.submit()}
        disabled={file.disabled}
      >
              submit
     </Button>
  </div> 
))}
```

And finally, modify the downloadFile function to update the button's disabled state on click

```
downloadFile = (file, index) => {
 let freshFiles = this.state.data;
 freshFiles[index].disabled = false;
 this.setState({data : freshFiles});

   //the rest of your code
}
```